# Create new element using number input

Tags: ionic3

I'm using ionic and I'm trying to make a function where I can use a number input from another page as variable to create new elements. So input number is on page A and I want to use that number to create new elements on page B. Anyone who can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar in our app. We send individuals through a questionnaire which is several slides inside of a component page. We have a class backing the overall questionnaire component page and store the value from the first page into a variable in that class. We then reference that variable in later slides to customize the experience.

Following along that same idea, you could use a Service/Provider (`ionic generate provider MyModel`). Then use that service to store values that can be referenced across various pages by injecting the provider into your page/component constructors like so:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyApp {

  constructor(
    public model: MyModelProvider) {
  }
}
```

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-ionic-share-data-between-pages-or-componenets-with-ng-or-something-related-ionic2/59515/5

Comment: And how should i write that function to create elements based on that number? Maybe its better to explain my app a little. If the user gives a number in page A, in page B will appear that amount of the same images, when you click on one of those images, that image will flip and show another (a little bit like a memory game)

Comment: In your second component, you would inject in the same provider and access the values (in your case, the number entered on the first page) you need to generate your template.  If the number is purely the number of images, I'd imagine you plan on iterating over some images collection and displaying them, so that number is your upper bound (or used in some function that randomizes which images to choose from your array). A lot of this depends on what your requirements are, of course.

Comment: And could i make that function in javascript? I can't find any easy way to use js files in ionic.

Comment: The component and service code, yes. Ionic 3 uses Typescript which gets compiled into Javascript.The template is obviously HTML.

Comment: @J.Bruyn does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NavController and NavParams to send and get data on another page.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/

```
import { NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public navParams: NavParams, public navCtrl: NavController) {}
```

In your page A you send your variable, like this when you change the page

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(RouteOfPageB,{
  variableName: variableData
});
```

In page B you get your data

```
this.navParams.get('variableName');
```

I hope that answers your question.